# Generating all subpacks of size N from a template pack

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-templates, combinatorics

`NSubsets<N, Pack<Types...>>::type` is to be the pack of packs consisting of all subsets of `Types...` of size N.
For example,

```
NSubsets<2, Pack<int, char, double>>::type
```

is to be

```
Pack<Pack<int, char>, Pack<int, double>, Pack<char, double>>
```

One method is to simply take the output of the `PowerSet` solution from [Obtaining all subpacks from a pack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28461300/obtaining-all-subpacks-from-a-pack/28464333#28464333),
and then remove each pack that are not of size N.  But this is way too inefficient for large N (and is plain bad anyway).  Here is my idea (inspired by the elegant solutions for `PowerSet`):
    Suppose we have `Pack<A,B,C,D>`, and N = 2.  Starting with `Pack<>`, we iterate through the types in `Pack<A,B,C,D>` and append each type like so:
Before appending anything, we have:

```
Pack<>
```

Appending A to the previous (and keeping the previous as well), we get:

```
Pack<>, Pack<A>
```

Appending B to the previous (and keeping the previous as well), we get:

```
Pack<>, Pack<A>, Pack<B>, Pack<A,B>,
```

but `Pack<A,B>` has size 2 so stash it away and take it out from this list, leaving us with:

```
Pack<>, Pack<A>, Pack<B>
```

Appending C to the previous (and keeping the previous as well), we get:

```
Pack<>, Pack<A>, Pack<B>, Pack<C>, Pack<A,C>, Pack<B,C>.
```

Like above, stash away `Pack<A,C>, Pack<B,C>`:

```
Pack<>, Pack<A>, Pack<B>, Pack<C>
```

Appending D to the previous (and keeping the previous as well), we get:

```
Pack<D>, Pack<A,D>, Pack<B,D>, Pack<C,D>.
```

Taking the ones of size 2 again, we now finally have

```
Pack<Pack<A,B>, Pack<A,C>, Pack<B,C>, Pack<A,D>, Pack<B,D>, Pack<C,D>>
```

as our desired output.

**Note that one flaw in this algorithm is keeping `Pack<>` in the second last step for no reason.  If N is bigger than 2, this extraneous part can really waste time.**
    The following is the code I have using the above method, but the output gives false, and I couldn't trace why (yet).  But even
if it did work correctly, I still don't like it too much, mainly because of the flaw above I just mentioned, and I don't know how
to remove that flaw either.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <int, typename> struct IsSize;

template <int N, template <typename...> class P, typename... Types>
struct IsSize<N, P<Types...>> : std::integral_constant<bool, sizeof...(Types) == N> {};

template <int, typename, typename, typename> struct PartitionPacksBySizeHelper;

template <int N, template <typename...> class P, typename... KeptPacks, typename... SizeNPacks>
struct PartitionPacksBySizeHelper<N, P<>, P<KeptPacks...>, P<SizeNPacks...>> {
    using not_sizeN_types = P<KeptPacks...>;
    using sizeN_types = P<SizeNPacks...>;
};

template <int N, template <typename...> class P, typename First, typename... Rest, typename... KeptPacks, typename... SizeNPacks>
struct PartitionPacksBySizeHelper<N, P<First, Rest...>, P<KeptPacks...>, P<SizeNPacks...>> : std::conditional<IsSize<N, First>::value,
        PartitionPacksBySizeHelper<N, P<Rest...>, P<KeptPacks...>, P<SizeNPacks..., First>>,
        PartitionPacksBySizeHelper<N, P<Rest...>, P<KeptPacks..., First>, P<SizeNPacks...>>
    >::type {};

template <int, typename> struct PartitionPacksBySize;

template <int N, template <typename...> class P, typename... Packs>
struct PartitionPacksBySize<N, P<Packs...>> : PartitionPacksBySizeHelper<N, P<Packs...>, P<>, P<>> {};

template <typename, typename> struct Append;

template <typename T, template <typename...> class P, typename...Types>
struct Append<T, P<Types...>> {
    using type = P<Types..., T>;
};

template <int, typename, typename, typename> struct NSubsetsHelper;

template <int N, template <typename...> class P, typename... CurrentPacks, typename... AccumulatedPacks>
struct NSubsetsHelper<N, P<>, P<CurrentPacks...>, P<AccumulatedPacks...>> {
    using type = P<AccumulatedPacks...>;
};

template <int N, template <typename...> class P, typename First, typename... Rest, typename... KeptPacks, typename... SizeNPacks>
struct NSubsetsHelper<N, P<First, Rest...>, P<KeptPacks...>, P<SizeNPacks...>>
    : NSubsetsHelper<N, P<Rest...>,
        typename PartitionPacksBySize<N, P<KeptPacks..., typename Append<First, KeptPacks>::type...>>::not_sizeN_types,
        typename PartitionPacksBySize<N, P<KeptPacks..., typename Append<First, KeptPacks>::type...>>::sizeN_types> {};

template <int, typename> struct NSubsets;

template <int N, template <typename...> class P, typename...Types>
struct NSubsets<N, P<Types...>> : NSubsetsHelper<N, P<Types...>, P<P<>>, P<>> {};

// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Testing

template <typename...> struct Pack {};

int main() {
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << std::is_same< NSubsets<2, Pack<int, char, double>>::type,
        Pack<Pack<int, char>, Pack<int, double>, Pack<char, double>>
    >::value << std::endl;  // false (darn!)
}
```

I traced on paper that the above pack should be the output, and when I change the order of the packs, it still gives false.  But still, the method is inferior anyway, as I mentioned above.  Any suggestions on a better method?

**Update:**  I found my mistake, and replaced

```
typename PartitionPacksBySize<N, P<KeptPacks..., typename Append<First, KeptPacks>::type...>>::sizeN_types>
```

with

```
typename Merge<P<SizeNPacks...>, typename PartitionPacksBySize<N, P<KeptPacks..., typename Append<First, KeptPacks>::type...>>::sizeN_types>::type
```

But still, you see how my algorithm really wastes time in the last N iterations when N is large?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is based on the `PowerPack` solution, but the filtering of too-long entries happens in each step and is therefore more efficient than just filtering at the end.

Step 1: `NAppend<N,Pack<...>,T>` only appends the new type `T` to the `Pack<...>` if it does not have more than `N` entries afterwards.

```
template<std::size_t,typename,typename>
struct NAppend
{
    using type = void;
};

template<std::size_t N,typename...Ts,typename T>
struct NAppend<N,Pack<Ts...>,T>
{
    using type =
        typename std::conditional<
            sizeof...(Ts)==N,
            void,
            Pack<Ts...,T>
        >::type;
};
```

Step 2: `ShrinkPack` removes `void` from a `Pack` of `Pack`s and `void`s.

```
template<typename,typename U=Pack<>>
struct ShrinkPack
{
    using type = U;
};

template<typename T,typename...Ts,typename...Us>
struct ShrinkPack<Pack<T,Ts...>,Pack<Us...>>
    : std::conditional<
        std::is_void<T>::value,
        ShrinkPack<Pack<Ts...>,Pack<Us...>>,
        ShrinkPack<Pack<Ts...>,Pack<Us...,T>>
      >::type
{
};
```

Step 3: `NPack` filters out all entries that are *not* of the right size.

```
template<std::size_t,typename,typename U=Pack<>>
struct NPack
{
    using type = U;
};

template<std::size_t N,typename...Ts,typename...Us,typename...Vs>
struct NPack<N,Pack<Pack<Ts...>,Us...>,Pack<Vs...>>
    : std::conditional<
        sizeof...(Ts)==N,
        NPack<N,Pack<Us...>,Pack<Vs...,Pack<Ts...>>>,
        NPack<N,Pack<Us...>,Pack<Vs...>>
      >::type
{
};
```

Final step: The adapted expansion, similar to `PowerPack` and applying `ShrinkPack` at each expansion step and `NPack` once at the end.

```
template<std::size_t N,typename,typename T=Pack<Pack<>>>
struct NPowerPack
{
    using type = typename NPack<N,T>::type;
};

template<std::size_t N,typename T,typename...Ts,typename...Us>
struct NPowerPack<N,Pack<T,Ts...>,Pack<Us...>>
    : NPowerPack<N,Pack<Ts...>,typename ShrinkPack<Pack<Us...,typename NAppend<N,Us,T>::type...>>::type>
{
};
```

Tests:

```
static_assert(std::is_same<
    NPowerPack<1,Pack<int, char, double>>::type,
    Pack<Pack<int>, Pack<char>, Pack<double>>
>(), "");

static_assert(std::is_same<
    NPowerPack<2,Pack<int, char, double>>::type,
    Pack<Pack<int, char>, Pack<int, double>, Pack<char, double>>
>(), "");
```

[**Live example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6ca3db74003ea600)

Answer (score 2):

We can generate precisely the subsets of size `k` from the outset - this will be more efficient in that we only need to do `O(n^k)` work instead of `O(2^n)` work. The algorithm here is just to iterate over all the permutations of words of `n` bits that have exactly `k` 1s, and for each word to add the appropriate `Pack`.

We start first with a bithack for finding the [next permutation](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#NextBitPermutation), in constexpr form:

```
constexpr int ctz(size_t n) {
    return n & 1 ? 0 : 1 + ctz(n >> 1); 
}

constexpr size_t next_perm_impl(size_t v, size_t t) {
    return (t + 1) | (((~t & -~t) - 1) >> (ctz(v) + 1));
}

constexpr size_t next_perm(size_t v) {
    return next_perm_impl(v, v | (v - 1));
}
```

Next I grab Columbo's accumulator that he deleted for some reason off the answer to your previous question:

```
template <class... T> struct Pack { using type = Pack; };

template <size_t size, class result, class>
struct accumulator : result { };

template <size_t j, class... R, class T1, class... T>
struct accumulator<j, Pack<R...>, Pack<T1, T...>>
: accumulator<(j>>1), typename std::conditional<j&1, Pack<R..., T1>, Pack<R...>>::type, Pack<T...>>
{};
```

Given a value `j`, we can determine the `Pack` associated with those elements. Now we just need to iterate from `(1 << k) - 1` up to `(1 << N) + (1 << (k-1)) - 1`. There's probably a more efficient way to do this, but the following works:

```
template <typename P, typename Result, size_t CUR, size_t LAST>
struct PowerPackImpl;

template <typename P, typename... R, size_t CUR, size_t LAST>
struct PowerPackImpl<P, Pack<R...>, CUR, LAST>
: PowerPackImpl<P,
                Pack<R..., typename accumulator<CUR, Pack<>, P>::type>,
                next_perm(CUR),
                LAST>
{ };

template <typename P, typename... R, size_t LAST>
struct PowerPackImpl<P, Pack<R...>, LAST, LAST>
: Pack<R...> { };

template <typename P, size_t K> struct PowerPack;

template <typename... P, size_t K>
struct PowerPack<Pack<P...>, K>
: PowerPackImpl<Pack<P...>, Pack<>, (1 << K) - 1, (1 << sizeof...(P)) + (1 << (K-1)) - 1>
{ };
```

For instance:

```
static_assert(std::is_same<
    typename PowerPack<Pack<int, char, double, float>, 1>::type,
    Pack<Pack<int>, Pack<char>, Pack<double>, Pack<float>>
>::value, "1 works");

static_assert(std::is_same<
    typename PowerPack<Pack<int, char, double, float>, 2>::type,
    Pack<Pack<int, char>, Pack<int, double>, Pack<char, double>, Pack<int, float>, Pack<char, float>, Pack<double, float> >
>::value, "2 works");
```